# Is it possible to COUNT using PARTITION BY?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a database in BigQuery where each record is a web traffic session on my website.

I currently have this table that tells me how a person came to my website and a column that tells me the order of each event.

The final goal is to see how many "not organic" sessions a person had to make until an organic session.

I am trying to create an additional column that will return "include" every time a conversion happened (when an organic session happened after a not organic session)

I know how to do this using Excel, but I don't know how to do this using SQL. I have a feeling that "PARTITION BY" is the solution, but I don't know how.

[image: database example]

Here is my Excel solution:

```
=IF(AND((COUNTIF($B$2:B2,FALSE))>=1,(IF(COUNTIF($B$2:B2,FALSE)>=1,COUNTIFS($B$2:B2,TRUE,$C$2:C2,">1"),0))>=1),"include","exclude")
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Comment: Hi, avoid adding images of code/data/errors in your questions. Here is why: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to add the `status` flag, then you seem to want the following rules:

- "exclude" for all inorganic sessions.
- "include" for all organic sessions before the first inorganic one.
- "include" for all other organic sessions.

If so, you can simply use:

```
select t.*
       (case when not is_organic then 'exclude'
             when countif(not is_organic) over (partition by partition by person_id order by sequence) = 0
             then 'exclude'
             else 'include'
        end) as status
from t;
```

However, for this question:

> The final goal is to see how many "not organic" sessions a person had to make until an organic session.

I would simply use aggregation with a window function:

```
select person_id, countif(sequence < first_organic_sequence)
from (select t.*,
             min(case when is_organic then sequence end) over (partition by person_id) as first_organic_sequence
      from t
     ) t
group by person_id;
```

Or if `sequence` always starts at `1` and how no gaps:

```
select person_id, min(case when is_organic then sequence end) - 1
from t
group by person_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following.  I created an intermediate CTE do define what the previous record was and then use that to determine the number of sessions to the first organic as well as your status.

```
with sample as (
    SELECT 1 as person_id, FALSE as is_organic, 1 as sequence
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 as person_id, TRUE as is_organic, 2 as sequence
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 as person_id, TRUE as is_organic, 3 as sequence
    UNION ALL  
    SELECT 2 as person_id, TRUE as is_organic, 1 as sequence
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 as person_id, FALSE as is_organic, 2 as sequence
),
modified  as (
    select *, 
        lag(is_organic)
            over(partition by person_id order by sequence ) as previous_indicator,
    from sample
)
select *,
    case when previous_indicator is not true then count(person_id) over(partition by person_id order by sequence) end as sessions_before_organic, 
    case when previous_indicator IS NOT NULL and is_organic = TRUE THEN 'include'
        else 'exlcude' 
    end as status
from modified;
```

Answer (score -1):

SQL Count with Partition By clause is one of the new powerful syntax that t-SQL developers can easily use. You can use this two command together based on this link:
https://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-count-function-with-partition-by-clause.aspx